# Python unit testing with PyTest, stuck on more advanced testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have been using PyTest for some time now to write some simple tests (like the ones you find in tutorials and youtube video's) and I thought now it was time to start writing actual test for our python scripts. The scripts are way more advanced than any shown in tutorials so I am getting a bit stuck. I do not want the entire correct answer, but rather a nudge in the right direction if possible. Here is my issue:

We have a script that reads a .md text file and converts it to a pdf file based on an external template. Part of the script is here below (I removed most of it because I first just want to have 1 running test)

```
class DocumentationEngine:

    def __init__(self, title, subtitle, series, style='TIIStyle_Digital_Aug_2020', templateFile='template.docet', tableOfContents=True, listOfFigures=False, listOfTables=False):
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.series = series
        self.style = style
        self.template = {}
        self.hasTOC = tableOfContents
        self.hasLOF = listOfFigures
        self.hasLOT = listOfTables
        self.loadTemplate(templateFile)

    def loadTemplate(self, file='template.docet'):
        with open(file, "r") as templatefile:
            lines = templatefile.readlines()
            key = "dummy"
            value = ""
            for line in lines:
                line = line.strip()
                if line.startswith('[') and line.endswith(']'):
                    self.template[key] = value
                    key = line[1:-1]
                    value = ""
                else:
                    value += line + '\n'

    def build(self, versions=[], content='', filename='Documenter\\_Autogenerated'):
        document = self.template["doc"]
        document = document.replace("%%style%%", self.style)
        document = document.replace("%%body%%",
                                    self.buildFirstPage() +
                                    self.buildTableOfContents() +
                                    self.buildListOfFigures() +
                                    self.buildListOfTables() +
                                    self.buildVersionTable(versions, filename) +
                                    self.buildContentPages(content=content) +
                                    self.buildLastPage()
                                    )
        return document


    def buildLastPage(self):
        return self.template["last_page"]
```

I am trying to write a simple unit test for the buildLastPage method and have been stuck for several days now.

I am not sure whether or not I need to mock the template file, use a fixture and/or if I can actually test only that method with all dependencies.

I started with the following:

```
from doceng import DocumentationEngine
import pytest


class Test:
    def test_buildLastPage(self):
        build_last_page = DocumentationEngine()

        assert build_last_page.template(1) == 1
```

which gives me an error regarding 3 required arguments. When adding the arguments like this:

```
from doceng import DocumentationEngine
import pytest


class Test:
    def test_buildLastPage(self, title, subtitle, series):
        build_last_page = DocumentationEngine()

        assert build_last_page.template(1) == 1
```

which gives me an error that the fixture is not found.

I added a fixture in conftest.py file like this:

```
import pytest
from doceng import DocumentationEngine


@pytest.fixture
def title(title):
    return title("test")
```

which will get me another error, recursive dependency involving fixture 'title' detected

I'm quite stuck so any nudge in the right direction for a newbie would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The error of the fixtures is regarding your test function `test_buildLastPage`. The way you are using it, it only needs the `self` argument.

A test function in pytest without any decorators always expects to find [fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/fixtures.html), that have the same name as the arguments. You did not define any fixtures and also do not use the arguments in your function. Therefore, you can remove them safely.

The actual error points `DocumentationEngine()`. The class expect 3 arguments when initializing the object. You set no arguments. Check your `__init__` function again to find the proper arguments.

Comment: Thanks Jonas,

It did point me a bit in the right direction but ultimately I had to change it massively. I fixed the issue by mocking the entire class with the correct args passed and merely manipulating the response while asserting the mock is called